# Laravel 5.6 ajax request, can't read the value

Tags: ajax, laravel

I can't read the values send with ajax request, i don't know what im missing.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $("#send").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var id = 5;

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/device/',
            data:{id:id},
            success:function(data){
                console.log('Yes' + data);
            }
        });
});
```

in the controller device i just dump the input from the ajax call

```
    $data = $request->all(); 
    dd($data);
```

I can't see the value send via ajax in the console, i only see Yes but not the data.
What im missing ?

Comment: When you check if is posting on the devTools is it posting?

Comment: What happens if you assign the value directly... as in data:{id:5},

Comment: var id = 5:  here should be semicolon instead of colon.

Comment: Yes i have semicolon sorry, when i post i made the mistake.

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?...From the docs: Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: that said, have you tried with done()

Comment: I have not tried with done(); i have the newest version of jQuery

Comment: docs said the callback you are using was removed... use done

Comment: Can you send an link from the doc ?

Comment: Try to add `dataType: json` in your ajax.

Answer (score 2):

use the following line in your controller;

`return $data;` instead of `dd($data)`;

Comment: again i don't see the value send eg 5, i see only Yes still no value.

Comment: I have in the controller only 
`$data = $request->all();`
`return ($data);`
its store controller with Request

Comment: I mean namespace and parameters controller function.

Comment: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller{
 public function test(Request $request){
  $data = $request->all(); 
  return $data;
 }
}`

Comment: I have normal post method witch was saving data before, data send from form with post method, not i just need to send the data via ajax.

Comment: take Request $request object as a function parameter. and use Illuminate\Http\Request; namespace

Comment: Yes i have included the Request

Answer (score 1):

Just Replace the + with , like below

```
 console.log('Yes' , data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
$("#send").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var id = 5:

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'{{url('/device')}}',
        data:{
             'ajax': 1,'id':id,'_token': {{csrf_token}}
             },
        success:function(data){
            console.log('Yes'+data.id);
        }
    });
```

});

In the controller use:

```
public function name()
{
  if(Input::get('ajax') == 1)
  {
   print_r('Ajax is working');die;
  }
}
```

Also make sure, in the route you have `post` or `any` and not `get` for this route.

Answer (score 0):

try this in controller

`public function store(Request $request) {
 return Response::json($request->all(), 200);
}`

dont forget to include 
"use Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;"

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

in controller:

```
return $data;
```

And simply replace + with, like this:

```
console.log('Yes' , data);
```